# Suppose $f(z)$ is entire and $Re(f(z))$ is bounded. Show that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a hint that states it might be helpful to consider $exp(f(z))$.

I don't see why having a real part would imply that the function is constant.

Comment: Can you express $e^{f(z)}$, in terms of the real part of $f$?

Comment: $e^{f(z)} = e^{Re(f) + i Im(f)} = e^{Re(f)}e^{i Im(f)}$

Comment: Then since the real part is bounded, there exists some $N$ such that for all $z \in \mathbb{C}, Re(f) \leq N$.  Thus $e^{f(z)} \leq e^M e^{i Im(f)}$, I'm not sure how that will lead to it being constant.

Comment: I think you can only use less-than in the reals, right? :)

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski $|\exp (i\cdot\text{ real number})|<\text{some number}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\exp(f(z))=\exp(\mathrm{Re\ }f(z))\exp(i\mathrm{Im\ }f(z))$ is bounded Liouville implies that $\exp(f(z))$ is constant and henceforth $f$ is constant.

Comment: $\exp w$ constant does not directly imply that $w$ is constant.