# Suppose that $f$ is an entire function with $Re[f(z)]\neq 0$ $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$Then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following theorem

> Suppose that $f$ is an entire function with $Re[f(z)]\neq 0$  $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is constant.

What I know is [Suppose $f(z)$ is entire and $Re(f(z))$ is bounded. Show that $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793635/suppose-fz-is-entire-and-refz-is-bounded-show-that-f-is-constant). This can be easily shown by $g(z) = e^{f(z)}$ and apply Liouville's theorem.

In this case $g(z) = e^{f(z)}$ and hence $|g(z)| = e^{\operatorname{Re}[f(z)]}$.

It seems $\operatorname{Re}[f(z)]\neq 0$ $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ does not imply boundeness.

How to show the above theorem is correct?

Comment: @MartinR, Oh Indeed you are right. Then I realized applying the same method by Kavi I can prove that problem too. For example, I can set $g(z) = e^{i f(z)}$ which is also the entire function and then apply Liouville's theorem to show $g(z)$ is constant. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\Re f(z)$ is a continuous function on the  complex plane (which is connected). If it is never $0$ it must be always positive or always negative. If it is always positive apply Liouville's Theorem to  at $e^{-f{(z)}}$ and if it is always negative apply Liouville's Theorem to  at $e^{f{(z)}}$.